# PHP fetch strings from different function

Tags: php

I have a function like this:

```
function colorscheme( $color, $url ) {
    return array( $color, $url );
}
```

How can I fetch them and display them like this *(this is an example, it doesn't work)*:

```
function fetch_colorscheme() {
    foreach() {
         echo "<ul><li>$color</li><li>$url</li></ul>";
    }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Your first function just returns a one-dimensional array, so just call the function and save the return value in a variable. Then you can access the array elements.

Comment: Honestly, your `colorscheme()` function is the most redundant thing I've ever seen.

Comment: ^Adding to what @Rizier123 said, here's a quick example, `foreach(colorscheme('yourColor', 'yourURL') as $key => $value){ echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br />'; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scheme = colorscheme('color', 'url');

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($scheme as $value) {
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Edit:

For multiple color schemes, you can do this:

```
$schemes = array(
    colorscheme('color 1', 'url 1'),
    colorscheme('color 2', 'url 2')
);
function fetch_colorscheme($schemes) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($schemes as $scheme) {
        foreach ($scheme as $value) {
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I'm sorry, I'm not able to test this at the moment.

Comment: Try using `sprintf` or `vsprintf` when building markup text, eg: `sprintf("<ul><li>%s</li><li>%s</li></ul>", $color, $url)`. It's more tidy IMHO.

Comment: That does it, but if someone adds multiple colorschemes, how would that work out?

Comment: And is it possible with just all function like in my example? thank you for your effort btw